# Mysql: Order rows by value frequency

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this table:

```
+----+------+---------+
| Id | Item | Country |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | b123 | Austria |
|  2 | a123 | Italy   |
|  3 | b990 | Germany |
|  4 | h231 | Austria |
|  5 | y233 | France  |
|  6 | u223 | Austria |
|  7 | p022 | Spain   |
|  8 | d133 | Italy   |
|  9 | w112 | Germany |
| 10 | j991 | Austria |
+----+------+---------+
```

I want to do a `SELECT` on that table and order the results by which `Country` is repeated the most.
So the expected output should be:

```
+----+------+---------+
| Id | Item | Country |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | b123 | Austria |
|  4 | h231 | Austria |
|  6 | u223 | Austria |
| 10 | j991 | Austria |
|  2 | a123 | Italy   |
|  8 | d133 | Italy   |
|  3 | b990 | Germany |
|  9 | w112 | Germany |
|  5 | y233 | France  |
|  7 | p022 | Spain   |
+----+------+---------+
```

How can I do that?

I have tried this:

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE Item != '' GROUP BY Item HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

But that will return something like this:

```
+----+------+---------+
| Id | Item | Country |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | b123 | Austria |
|  8 | d133 | Italy   |
|  3 | b990 | Germany |
|  5 | y233 | France  |
|  7 | p022 | Spain   |
+----+------+---------+
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `DISTINCT` keyword after the `SELECT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A - Original table
B - Getting the counts at Country Level.
```

By joining A and B we can sort the data in descending order of count as well as display all the items from the table.

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM items A
INNER JOIN 
(    SELECT Country,COUNT(*) AS cnt       
      FROM items 
     WHERE Item != '' 
     GROUP BY Item 
) B
   ON A.Country = B.Country
ORDER BY B.cnt DESC,A.Country,A.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include a subquery in the `order by`.  So one method is:

```
select i.*
from items i
where i.item <> ''
order by (select count(*) from items i2 where i2.item = i.item) desc;
```

This approach has advantages and disadvantages as compared to doing a `group by` and joining in the value:

- Advantage:  It can take advantage of an index on `items(item)`.
- Advantage:  If the `where` clause is highly selective, it calls the subquery only once per row.
- Disadvantage:  If the `where` clause is not highly selective, it calls the subquery only once per row.